# QGIS 3.8 Batch Processing file path using Caclulate by Expression has square brackets between strings

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, batch

I am trying to run a batch process using QGIS 3.8. I want to have the name of the output file use part of the name of the input file. For example the input file is "Landuse_A.tif" and the output is "Degradation_A.tif".  Using the Calculate by Expression function in the output file I use the expression

```
"C:/Users/BP/Desktop/" || "Degradation" || regexp_substr( @landuse ,'(?:.(?!_))+$')||".tif"
```

This seems like it should work but puts brackets between my strings. The result is

> [C:/Users/BP/Desktop/][Degradation]_A[.tif]

and the file path is not recognized by the computer.

Are the brackets really messing things up or is it something else and if they are what can I do to remove them?

Comment: I think the double quotation marks are a problem. Double quotation marks mean the string inside is a field name. Use single quotation marks for a normal string. See if it works as `'C:/Users/BP/Desktop/' || 'Degradation' || regexp_substr( @landuse ,'(?:.(?!_))+$')||'.tif'`

Comment: That was it- I got my double quotes and single quotes backwards. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer I know it is a silly mistake but others may have made the same one?

Comment: absolutely. i'm glad it was that simple to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotation marks are the problem. Double quotation marks mean the string inside is a field name. Use single quotation marks for a normal string.

```
'C:/Users/BP/Desktop/' || 'Degradation' || regexp_substr( @landuse ,'(?:.(?!_))+$')||'.tif'
```